# How many kWh this turbine would generate?

Tags: energy, electricity, experimental-physics, rotation

My grandfather and I are running some experiments down the river, however we don't have expertise in physics so I bring up this question to the community and hope someone could help.

How many kWh a turbine with the following features would generate?

[image: Just a simple prototype]
[image: Just a simple prototype]

These images are just a simple prototype which does not apply some of the following features:

Shape: Reel.

Length: 1.50m.

Diameter: 1.20m. (Including its palettes and axis which has the thickness of 20cm.)

10 Longitudinal/helical palettes with length of 1.50m., thickness of 2cm. and height of 50cm.

Total weight: 50kg. (Palettes and axis included for torque boost.)

River conditions:

Speed: 3 meters per second.

Depth: 20m.

It would be installed 2 meters beneath the river surface, placed horizontally.

Comment: You seem to have done this backwards. You have decided how your turbine will be made and are asking how well it will work in your river. You should start with conditions of your river and find out what kind of turbine would work best. It will not be a simple thing to design a good turbine. Just to begin, there are several kinds. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_turbine or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_wheel. We don't have the expertise to design one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum theoretical power that a turbine can develop in the absence of any efficiency losses is given by the product of the mass flow rate through it times the pressure drop across it, taking care of units. Any real-world turbine will deliver less than this.

This means that without knowing the pressure drop or the flow rate, no estimate of your turbine's power output can be determined.